# Using extra fonts with RStudio's Shiny when downloading reports (LaTeX)

Tags: fonts, latex, shiny, rstudio

I have developed a shinyapp that allows users to upload their data and explore the results of a standard analysis, and then download a report based on this (using a .Rnw file I uploaded with the shinyapp). We use Open Sans font a lot, and I have tried to specify this in the .Rnw file (with `\usepackage{opensans}`) but this doesn't work when deployed to Shiny.

My question is does anyone know how to add fonts that aren't already installed on the latex engine that Shiny uses? Can this be done on the fly, or perhaps locally within the folder uploaded with the shinyapp?

Answer (score 0):

Download the .otf files of the fonts you wish to use and place them in the same shiny app directory where there is your .rmd document.

In your **.rmd** file change the YAML as following:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Times.otf}[
    BoldFont = Times-bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = Times-italic.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = Times-bolditalic.otf]
---
````

in your **server.R**, inside the `downloadHandler()` function to generate the report, copy to a temporary directory also the .otf file along with your .rmd file:

```
file.copy(from = "Country_report.Rmd",
          to = tempdir_Country_report,
          overwrite = TRUE)

file.copy(from = "Times.otf",
          to = tempdir_TimesNormal,
          overwrite = TRUE)
```

When deploying the application on shinyapps.io server, be sure to upload every file (.rmd and .otf) online.

Credits for this answer to [Ralf Stubner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/140850/ralf-stubner) for the solution reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516141/deploy-custom-fonts-to-shinyapps-io-for-application-that-produces-an-r-markdown/516382?noredirect=1#comment1305808_516382).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24579923)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know. I edited my answer

Comment: @GalNaor could you remove the -1 now?